# How do I solve a thermal issue on my HP dv6 laptop?

Tags: 12.04, hybrid-graphics, cpufreq

I have HP DV6 6080 laptop with Sandy Bridge ci7 CPU and ATI graphic.

I have thermal issue and power usage in Ubuntu. I followed the instructions from [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) to install hybrid graphic because I want to my laptop become cool in Ubuntu.

But after doing so, my laptop thermal doesn't become cool. I tried to install new kernel 3.4 in order to fix these issues but after installing, it doesn't boot in high graphic mode and need to me reconfigure graphic.

How can I reconfigure graphic? And how can I fix thermal issue in my laptop with 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a dv7 for years (I think from Ubuntu 10.04). Of course it is not Sandy Bridge, but I have the same issue. After a lot of tries during these years I understood there is nearly no way to avoid the heat. But *this is normal and doesn't harm your laptop*.

Important note: This is a personal experience on a laptop different than yours. May be you were more lucky than me and find a good way on your computer.

Comment: When i use ubuntu 11.10 i can somedeal make my laptop become cool! with some techniques that are useful in older version of ubuntu! but when i hear about fixing power regression in kernel i don't know these techniques can useful in this version or no!.I have another issue after install new kernel and my graphic doesn't work!.How can i make it work?